# Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to give a php file a permission to write to JSON file, but it does not seem to work. here is my code

```
<?php
$light = $_GET['light'];
if($light == "on") {
  $file = fopen("light.json", "w") or die("can't open file");
  fwrite($file, '{"light": "on"}');
  fclose($file);
} 
else if ($light == "off") {
  $file = fopen("light.json", "w") or die("can't open file");
  fwrite($file, '{"light": "off"}');
  fclose($file);
}

chmod(" /home/daffo/public_html/ard/light.json", 0755);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe the space before the first slash on path is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the space before the first slash:

```
chmod("/home/daffo/public_html/ard/light.json", 0755);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious, removing the space before your first slash:

```
chmod("/home/daffo/public_html/ard/light.json", 0755);
```

You'll run into trouble creating your own `json`. Do it using in-built functions:

```
fwrite($file, json_encode(array("light"=> "off")));
```